# Combine columns from two dataframes into one

Tags: python, pandas

I have a series that I split into two since the parts contain terms that need to be processed differently. Afterwards I want to merge the two split series (actually, after the processing they are now two-column dataframes) in the order they originally were. I have almost solved it:

```
import pandas as pd
terms = pd.Series(["oo1", "oo2", "oo3", "aa1", "aa2", "oo4"], name="term")

# 0    oo1
# 1    oo2
# 2    oo3
# 3    aa1
# 4    aa2
# 5    oo4
terms_oo = terms[terms.apply(lambda term: "oo" in term)]

# 0    oo1
# 1    oo2
# 2    oo3
# 5    oo4
terms_aa = terms[terms.apply(lambda term: "aa" in term)]

# 3    aa1
# 4    aa2

# process differently so you end up with
df_aa = pd.concat([terms_aa, pd.Series(["taa1", "taa2"], index=[3, 4])], axis=1)
df_aa.columns = ["term", "annotations"]

#    term annotations
# 3  aa1  taa1
# 4  aa2  taa2

df_oo = pd.concat([terms_oo, pd.Series(["too1", "too2", "too3", "too4"], index=[0, 1, 2, 5])], axis=1)
df_oo.columns = ["term", "annotations"]

#   term annotations
# 0  oo1  too1
# 1  oo2  too2
# 2  oo3  too3
# 5  oo4  too4
```

Now I want to combine `df_aa` and `df_oo` so that they have the original order as in `terms` and so that `annotations` is one column including the values from `df_aa` and `df_oo`. How do I do that?

I tried the following, but I can't find the last step needed:

```
terms_df = pd.DataFrame(terms)
m1 = terms_df.merge(df_aa, on="term", how="outer")
m2 = m1.merge(df_oo, on="term", how="outer")

#  term annotations_x annotations_y
# 0  oo1           NaN          too1
# 1  oo2           NaN          too2
# 2  oo3           NaN          too3
# 3  aa1          taa1           NaN
# 4  aa2          taa2           NaN
# 5  oo4           NaN          too4
```

Above I want to merge the annotations column into one. They should be mutually exclusive (nans in one has a value in another).

Here is what I have tried:

```
m2["annotations"] = m2[pd.isnull(m2["annotations_x"])]["annotations_y"]

m2
#   term annotations_x annotations_y annotations
# 0  oo1           NaN          too1        too1
# 1  oo2           NaN          too2        too2
# 2  oo3           NaN          too3        too3
# 3  aa1          taa1           NaN         NaN
# 4  aa2          taa2           NaN         NaN
# 5  oo4           NaN          too4        too4

m2["annotations"] = m2[pd.isnull(m2["annotations_y"])]["annotations_x"]
m2
#  term annotations_x annotations_y annotations
# 0  oo1           NaN          too1         NaN
# 1  oo2           NaN          too2         NaN
# 2  oo3           NaN          too3         NaN
# 3  aa1          taa1           NaN        taa1
# 4  aa2          taa2           NaN        taa2
# 5  oo4           NaN          too4         NaN
```

I included this whole long thing because what I originally wanted to do is probably possible to do in very few lines. So I instead of just showing my final problem I included the whole thing, since the final problem I am struggling with now could probably have been avoided had I been cleverer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Use `append()` and `sort()`

There is no need to do anything complicated here. The index is preserved so you can simply append them and sort them

```
result = df_oo.append(df_aa).sort()
print(result)

  term annotations
0  oo1        too1
1  oo2        too2
2  oo3        too3
3  aa1        taa1
4  aa2        taa2
5  oo4        too4
```

Comment: Using  pandas, if what you are trying to achieve feels to complicated, it probably is :)